# Campaign Influence Model - Even Distribution

Tags: campaign-influence

I turned on Campaign Influence and it appears to be working correctly. When a contact is added to a campaign, that influence is showing in the new related list of the opportunity.

Primary campaign source is getting 100% attribution.

We want to move to an even distribution of influence(%) for all campaigns on a given opportunity. I was able to use dataloader to populate all legacy opps but I'm not clear on how to do that going forward.

I understand that I would create a new model(Customize >> Campaigns >> Campaign Influence >> Model Settings) for the even distribution, let's call it `Even Distribution`

SFDC videos and docs all show you how to create/change the `Campaign Influence Model` but gloss over what happens next.

Do I need code to do this? Is there some boilerplate? I can't be the first person to try to do this.

Answer (score -1):

The Salesforce influence model attributes 100% revenue credit to the primary campaign and 0% to any other campaigns users assign to an opportunity. Only the Salesforce influence model supports auto-association. Auto-association adds campaigns to opportunities automatically when the contact on an opportunity is also a member of a campaign.

To attribute revenue more flexibly to campaigns, you or your partners can create custom influence attribution models. For example, create a model that evenly distributes credit for an opportunity across all campaigns that touched it. Or create a model that gives 100% credit to the first or last campaign that touched an opportunity. With Customizable Campaign Influence, you can create a model for virtually any scenario that suits your business.
If you’d like to prevent your sales or marketing users from adding or editing campaign influence records, you can lock any of your attribution models. Records for locked models can only be updated via the API."

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pBFVQA2#ext-gen25

Comment: This does not answer his primary question around if we need to use apex